# Android MediaCodec appears to buffer H264 frames

Tags: android, opengl-es, h.264, android-mediacodec

I'm manually reading a RTP/H264 stream and pass the H264 frames to the Android MediaCodec. I use the "markerBit" as a border for the frames. The MediaCodec is tied to a OpenGL Texture (SurfaceTexture). 
In general everything works fine. But the Decoder appears to buffer frames. If I put a frame in the decoder it is not rendered immediately to the texture. After I put 2-3 frames more in the decoder the first frame is rendered to the texture.

I'm implementing against Android 4.4.4.

```
private static final int INFINITE_TIMEOUT = -1;
private static final int TIMEOUT_OUTPUT_BUFFER_MEDIA_CODEC = 1000;
...
int bufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(INFINITE_TIMEOUT);
if (bufferIndex < 0) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Error");
}

ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[bufferIndex];
inputBuffer.clear();

// Copy H264 data to inputBuffer
h264Frame.fill(inputBuffer);

codec.queueInputBuffer(bufferIndex, 0, inputBuffer.position(), 0, 0);
drainOutputBuffers();
...
```

and

```
private boolean drainOutputBuffers() {
MediaCodec.BufferInfo buffInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(buffInfo, TIMEOUT_OUTPUT_BUFFER_MEDIA_CODEC);

if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
  codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, true);
  return true;
}

switch (outputBufferIndex) {
  case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
    LOG.debug("Could not dequeue output buffer. Try again later");
    break;
  case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
    LOG.warn("The output format has changed.");
    break;
  case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
    LOG.warn("The output buffers has changed.");
    break;
  default:
    LOG.warn("The output buffer index was negative: {}", outputBufferIndex);
}
return false;
}
```

On the rendering side I use the "onFrameAvailable" callback for checking if I have to update the texture on the openGl Thread. The flag I use for checking is guarded by a lock (synchronized).

I suspect that the presentation timestamp may influence the rendering. But I set it to 0. Thus I assume the frame should be rendered without a delay.

I'd like to have the frame rendered to the texture without having to put additional frames.

Comment: I don't think it's the nature for h264 decoder, it's most likely a flaw in MediaCodec. If I do this on a PC using ffmpeg there is no delay.

Answer (score 2):

From the MediaCodec **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)**

> The Executing state has three sub-states: Flushed, Running and
>   End-of-Stream. Immediately after `start()` the codec is in the Flushed
>   sub-state, where it holds all the buffers. As soon as the first input
>   buffer is dequeued, the codec moves to the Running sub-state, where it
>   spends most of its life. **When you queue an input buffer with the
>   end-of-stream marker, the codec transitions to the `End-of-Stream`
>   sub-state**. In this state the codec no longer accepts further input
>   buffers, but still generates output buffers until the end-of-stream is
>   reached on the output. You can move back to the Flushed sub-state at
>   any time while in the Executing state using flush().

You need to "queue an input buffer with the `end-of-stream` marker". Do this with the first frame you feed to the decoder (make sure it is a keyframe).

This point is to tell the decoder not to expect anymore frames and therefore begin playback immediately. Otherwise it's normal to feed 3 or 4 frames before seeing anything. This an expectation of all MPEG decoders and is not Android-related.

Comment: When I send an end-of-stream flag along with the first key frame, the mediacodec stops working.

Comment: In that **[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)** I posted, scroll down to "States" and read that carefully onwards. Consider using `flush()` on the decoder also. The point is : every frame is part of a **G**roup **O**f **P**ictures (eg: **I** is followed by **P** & **B** frames). P & B always need **I** (keyframe) so it's kept aside for reference whilst you send 3 or 4 (P or B) frames before you see anything. The point of "`end of stream`" and "`flush`" is equal to saying "there is nothing after my keyframe, display it now".

Comment: I meant read the link and apply what the documentation says. Your problem lies in the MPEG decoder holding a keyframe (full picture) aside for reference by some P and B type frames (those have less picture info, so they get missing parts from the keyframe). Dequeue the stream, if that helps. The solution is to somehow tell the system, that after the one frame you sent for decoding, the stream is now over & so it sends the data through to the decoder (display picture)...

Comment: @VC.One This method seems to only work when every frames are I frames. How to resolve this when there are P frames in the stream?

Comment: @user3667089, send your P/B-frames together with the I-frame (key frame) as one large chunk of bytes (stream). Always have a key frame as first frame in the bytes you send.

Comment: @VC.One My application is real-time streaming so I don't have future frames available to bundle. How to resolve this?

Comment: @user3667089 yes but you don't send one frame at a time, you store from keyframe and any future frames up to next detected keyframe, then send to decoder whilst strong from this next keyframe onwards to repeat process... _for example :_ In a 30 fps video, you could store 1 keyframe + 29 frames then send that chunk to decoder (decoder gets a 1 second worth of video data to display). Your setup may make more than 29 P/B frames so keep them all & stop when a new keyframe is generated (repeat process from new keyframe)..

Comment: @VC.One Yes but in your example that means I will have 30 frames of delay. When I have the frames available I need to display it immediately because of the real time requirement.

Comment: @user3667089 You could try **`releaseOutputBuffer`** after each frame. I can't test for you cos am not Android SDK developer. In AS3 language (Flash) its possible to append frame by frame, from keyframe it expects a minimum of 4 additional P/B frames (ie: a fraction of 1 second must be pre-bufered before playback). In my example 30 frames would mean a 1 sec delay but maybe your system will play sooner like after 1 keyframe + a few more P frames. Just test the options. MPEG is akward like that (needs keyframe, buffer must be filled to a minimum size, has "group of pictures" system, etc etc)...

Comment: @VC.One I am already doing releaseOutputBuffer after each frame but still it won't output P frames immediately. Also this shouldn't be a MPEG problem, because I am able to get zero latency decoding on a desktop with the likes of ffmpeg and NVIDIA Video Codec SDK.

Comment: Are you sure its zero decoding latency or it just appears to be instant (cos it's fast)? If you try a different codec like VP6 or VP8 you will see it works smoother than MPEG, even allows backwards frame appending (try that with MPEG & see if you still like the corrupt pixels it shows). **About your issue** : A P-frame is not a full picture (just changed ones from last frame), so decoder still needs some pixels from keyframe to display a full frame. You have to work with **that** understanding. I'll check the Android manual & advise later.

Answer (score 1):

**If anyone looking at this in 2021:**
Mediacodec May or may not hold frames (of course. I-frames I mean). It totally depends on the device. If you want to be sure the frame is released, for example when you plan to decode a single frame, you can use

```
mediaCodec.stop
```

every time you put the data in input buffer so it releases the frame. Afterwards, you have to again start the mediaCodec for next frame.

Answer (score -2):

Mediacodec decoder buffers 6-7 frames before outputting first decoded output frame. It seems to flaw in the mediacodec. This will be problem in the streaming application.
So far my debugging shows decoding H264 with mediacodec has 6-7 frames delay during start of the stream.